# Why is quixotic not Quixotic (a proper adjective)?

Tags: adjectives, capitalization, proper-nouns, proper-adjectives

Adjectives derived from proper nouns are known as proper adjectives, and are capitalized:

A piece of writing could be Shakespearean, not shakespearean.
A person may be Canadian, not canadian.

Even Chrome's spellchecker sees these as correct and incorrect.

However, quixotic is written in lowercase, despite coming from the name of the character Don Quixote.  Similarly, draconian laws are named for Draco, a particularly brutal senator from ancient Athens.

Does anyone know the reasoning behind some proper adjectives not being capitalized in common usage?

Comment: @only_pro - thank you.  I came across this while writing up a post for a linguistic-oriented Facebook group I recently created.  Was scheduling some words of the day, writing up quixotic, and realized it looked weird capitalized.  Did some poking around and realized that there's no discernible rhyme or reason to which do and which do not get capitalized.  Made the back of my brain tickle.

Comment: Because English!

Comment: Related: [Why is “biblical” the only proper adjective to not use upper case?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/133177/216106).

Comment: I had no idea that quixotic came from Don Quixote, probably due to people pronouncing it very differently. "Quick sotic" vs "qijote".

Comment: @ViktorMellgren English-speaking people may say 'Don Quijote' nowadays, but the book was translated into English a long time ago when most people had less exposure to foreign languages, and the name was traditionally pronounced 'Quicksote'.

Comment: In Hamlet, Act 3, Scene 2, our hero says,  _I would have such a fellow whipped for o'erdoing Termagant; it out-herods Herod._., thus not capitalising a noun-derived verb when the noun from which it is derived is **standing right next to it!**

Comment: @OscarBravo - I'm not sure that 17th century grammar is applicable to modern English. Also since Shakespeare himself spelled his own name 20+ different ways, he may not be an appropriate authority.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In a comment posted years ago to the question [Why is "biblical" the only proper adjective to not use upper case?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133177/why-is-biblical-the-only-proper-adjective-to-not-use-upper-case) I listed some other exceptions to the general rule that the first letter of an adjective derived from a proper name is normally capitalized. Only the letters *q*, *w*, *x*, and *y* did not yield an example (for some reason, I failed to notice *quixotic*):

> *arabesque*, *byzantine*, *caesarean*, *draconian*, *epicurean*, *faradic*, *galvanic*, *herculean*, *italic*, *jesuitical*, *kabbalistic*, *lilliputian*, *mercurial*, *nazi*, *oedipal*, *pyrrhic*, *rubenesque*, *spartan*, *terpsichorean*, *utopian*, *voltaic*, and *zephyrous*

Why do these exceptions occur? The not-very-satisfactory answer seems to be that common usage determines whether an adjective based on a proper name is initial-capped or lowercased. Dictionaries provide their spelling preferences based on what amount to the found objects of preponderant real-world usage in each case; and thenceforth, real-world usage (to the extent that it is influenced by people who look things up in dictionaries) tends to reflect the dictionary treatment. The very circularity of the process makes it extremely difficult to determine where and when the critical decision regarding initial cap versus all lowercase got made.

I don't see how else to explain why *Oedipal* is usually initial-capped when it refers to the mythical character Oedipus (as in "Oedipal resistance to fate") but usually lowercased when it refers to Freud's Oedipus complex (as in "oedipal feelings"), although the complex is explicitly named after Oedipus.

Bryan Garner, [*Garner's Modern American Usage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=18NMAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA128&dq=%22why+Stone+Age+is+capitalized+but+space+age+is+usually+not%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH0O3ZscvgAhWT6FQKHUIICcQQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22why%20Stone%20Age%20is%20capitalized%20but%20space%20age%20is%20usually%20not%22&f=false), second edition (2003) concludes that trying to explain exceptions to the normal rules about what gets capitalized and what doesn't is a fool's game:

> There is simply no way to reason out why *Stone Age* is capitalized but *space age* is usually not, why *October* is capitalized but *autumn* is not, why in scientific names the genus is capitalized but the species is not—even when the species name is derived from a proper name {*Rhinolophus philippinensis*}.

Ultimately, capitalization conventions rest on strong general tendencies tempered by exceptions that are neither consistent nor explicable.

Comment: Oddly, I can recall, in my school days, being instructed that "Autumn" is capitalized, though "fall", "winter", "spring", and "summer" are not.

Comment: A *60-watt* bulb? Alas, neither Xerxes nor Xenophon nor Deng Xiaoping seem to have inspired this. And when people think of a Xanadu, they think of Coleridge’s poem and remember it’s a real place.

Comment: @HotLicks I never heard that one. *Autumn* comes from a common noun in Latin, and was first used by Chaucer in his *Boece* (with the explanation, “that is, the end of somer.”) I can’t think of any basis for such a rule either in etymology or historical usage or a desire to be more sensitive to, I don’t know, deciduous trees. I guess it’s one of those completely arbitrary rules somebody made up to be able to call everybody else wrong.

Comment: @Davislor: You'd think that _Watt_ ought to be at least as adjective-friendly as _Faraday_, _Galvani_, or _Volta_, but historically (at least) that bulb won't glow, despite our wattliest efforts.

Comment: @SvenYargs I **very occasionally** see *Doylist* and *Watsonian* uncapitalized, but that is the exception, not the rule. That is, out-of-universe versus in-universe explanations of some aspect of a work of fiction: Respectively, “Why did Sir Arthur Conan Doyle write that?” versus “Why would Dr. Watson have written that to his literary agent?”

Comment: Anyway, I’d say one rule of thumb there is that, the more irrelevant, mythological or forgotten the original namesake is, the more likely English-speakers are today to stop capitalizing it. This is also especially likely to happen if the word appears in parallel with uncapitalized antonyms. People are more likely to think of *lesbian* as parallel to *gay* or *straight* than to know or care that the ancient poet Sappho lived on the island of Lesbos. Caesarean section is borderline, but the Imperial Presidency is always Caesarism because Julius Caesar is best-known for becoming a dictator.

Comment: It is strange that no one capitalizes *laconic*, though, since everyone who knows what it means has heard “If.” And I sometimes wonder if there are people self-aware enough to make the distinction, “Oh, I was calling him a genocidal, authoritarian warmonger in general, not a literal member of the National Socialist German Workers’ Party.”

Comment: For the list of given examples, it seems like in there is a meaningful distinction to be made between "reminiscent of/similar to X" and "belonging to the actual X", which can be a very good reason to not capitalize the former, and captalize the latter.

Comment: @Flater: Yes, that sounds reasonable enough. But in practice Merriam-Webster's endorses _Orwellian_, _Machiavellian_, and _Kafkaesque_ even when what a writer means to convey is "vaguely reminiscent of Orwell [or Machiavelli or Kafka]." And I see no difference in attributive precision between _rubenesque_ and, say, _Modiglianiesque_; the difference there seems to be that the lowercased word is far more familiar than the intiial-capped one. But the opposite result occurs with _Homeric_ and _sapphic_, when applied to types of verse. So, in terms of predictability, it's a very tough go.

Comment: @Davislor: Scientists being scientists, there is a consciously-chosen convention about capitalization of units.  Specifically, [units of measurement are always uncapitalized](https://www.nist.gov/pml/weights-and-measures/writing-metric-units), which explains why watt, farad, newton, and tesla are lower-case even though they're derived from proper nouns.  That said, scientists are also human, and so there's one exception in the SI:  "degrees Celsius".

Comment: @Davislor: Consider me a counterexample :). I've heard *laconic* used enough to know what it means without ever learning the history of the word.

Comment: @Anyon: No, I should have included "y" in the could-not-find list, and now I have—thanks! I don't doubt that _yterbium_ and _ytrium_ have adjective forms, but they are too obscure for _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh College Dictionary_ (the source of the listed lowercase adjectives) to acknowledge.

Comment: @Michael Seifert: If you think of _Fahrenheit_ and _Celsius_ not as unit names but as modifiers of the implicit word "scale," they fall into line with a number of other such initial-capped words (_Brazelton_, _Mercalli_, _Mohs'_, _Richter_, _Scoville_, etc.—although you have to wonder about that apostrophe after _Mohs_).

Comment: Mathematics has a lot of these, and again, there is no clear pattern.  Some are usually capitalized (*Pythagorean, Archimedean, Lagrangian*), some are almost always uncapitalized (*abelian*), and some are done different ways by different authors (*Euclidean/euclidean, Gaussian/gaussian*).  There's sort of a vague feeling that *not* capitalizing the word is somehow a higher honor to the inventor, as if their name has turned into a common word.

Comment: @NateEldredge Same deal in physics. I can't remember where I first saw/heard it explicitly stated, but something along the lines of "the second greatest honour in physics is to having something named after you, the greatest honour is to have something that people forget is named after you". The Hubble constant might get a new name at some point, but I can't imagine people calling bosons and fermions something different.

Comment: @Davislor - Just for reference this memory of "Autumn" is from about the 3rd grade, ca 1957.

Answer (score 28):

As you correctly say, technically words associated with a proper noun should be capitalized.

However as time and usage goes on, these words tend to become words in their own right, not associated any more with the person they are named after.

So 'Shakespearean' means 'associated with or like Shakespeare'. It has no meaning apart from the association with the person.

On the other hand 'quixotic' is defined as "foolishly impractical especially in the pursuit of ideals. especially : marked by rash lofty romantic ideas or extravagantly chivalrous action". The definition makes no reference to Quixote, and people can (and do) use the word without knowing who Don Quixote is. This is even more true with 'draconian', which I had no idea was related to a person. Over time the adjective morphs from directly referring to the person etc, to indicating characteristics that were once associated with that person but are now considered independently.

It's likely that this morph happens over time, with some people starting to use lowercase while others keep the initial cap. Something similar happens with genericised trademarks, where words like google, hoover, trampoline and band aid lose their capitalization over time.

So the answer is that **the word loses its initial cap when it stops being associated with the person (or thing) it was originally associated with.**

Comment: that's an interesting observation, and I would agree, but then what of `biblical`, which is ostensibly 'associated with the Bible', but still not commonly capitalized.  Interestingly, I actually do capitalize Biblical, as rarely as I write the word. I'm fairly certain that I generally capitalize Draconian as well.  But Quixotic just sort of felt wrong.  It's a fickle thing, English...

Comment: +1 for confirming that I’m not the only one who had no idea _draconian_ was related to a person – I just thought it was a direct reference to ‘dragon-like’!

Comment: William Blake wrote 'dark Satanic mills' in 'Jerusalem', in 1804, but by 2012 the word  'satanic' was sufficiently disconnected from the evil one for the Guardian to lowercase it when discussing the poem.

Comment: A minor point is that "quixotic" is not given a Spanish pronunciation.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but I doubt it's correct. Take a look at the question Davo linked to in a comment on the question.  There are a good number of proper adjectives that are commonly not capitalized and it's not clear to me that *Faustian* has any more connection to *Faust* than *herculean* has to *Hercules*, or that *balkanization* is less associated with the Balkans than *Americanization* is with America.

Comment: I completely agree with the answer to the question Davo linked to, which says essentially the same as mine here. 'balkanization' (meaning fragmentation) is no longer associated with the Balkans, although Americanization definitely refers to America.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - to be fair, I wouldn't use The Guardian as a definitive reference for grammar or spelling. They've had a reputation over the years for some spectacular howlers.

Comment: @Juhasz I suspect that this is the best explanation for the trend, but given that its human language and not, perhaps, (classical) physics, the trend is weak and full of confounding factors and sub-trends

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Blake's use of capitalisation does not necessarily reflect convention at the time, e.g. in London he capitalises 'Man', 'Infant', 'Church', 'Soldiers', 'Palace', 'Chimney-sweepers', 'Harlots' and 'Marriage', probably for emphasis, or maybe to indicate the ideal rather than an individual.

Answer (score 6):

Salads can tell us something:

- [Caesar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_salad)
- [Cobb](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobb_salad)
- [Waldorf](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waldorf_salad)
- [Greek](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_salad)

Even though these are very common salads, and likely to be served in a variety of ways, their names are usually capitalized.

BTW, I’m using the Wikipedia for consistency, but if you search for them on the internet, the recipe websites tend to follow the same usage.

On the other hand, the [porterhouse steak](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-bone_steak), which the OED attributes to the Porter House eatery in early nineteenth century New York, has lost its capital letter. My theory is that contention over the origin (and differences over what a porterhouse actually is) must have played a role in this.

But I have no larger theory to present, especially since with sauces like Hollandaise and Bearnaise, the English have capitalized what were originally lower case French adjectives, *hollandaise* and *bearnaise*.

Comment: Definitely an interesting addition to the conversation, especially the latter with regard to the sauces. Obviously in the end common usage trumps anything related to grammar or syntax when it comes to English, so it's not surprising, necessarily, that these changes occur.  It is surprising how seemingly random they can be.

Comment: Consider this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayonnaise. From what I can see in everyday life, *mayonnaise* doesn’t rate a capital M. The opinion of Alexandre Balthazar Laurent Grimod de La Reynière is interesting

Comment: that's interesting.  But with the etymology itself unclear, it's certainly not proper.

Comment: I think your salads retain their initial caps because they are the proper names of salads, regardless of their association with people or places.